# load html link into div

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, load

I have list of links in a div...when i click on link I want to load the link content in another div in the same page, here is my code :

```
<div>
 <div>
    <div style="padding-bottom:20px;">
       <center><img src="real.gif"></center>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div>
            <div style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                <a href="history.html"><h3>History of Club</h3></a>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                <a href=""><h3>Photos Gallery</h3></a>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                <a href=""><h3>Hall of Fame</h3></a>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                <a href=""><h3>History of Club</h3></a>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="linkcontent"></div>
```

can I do that by a very simple js function ? any suggestions?

Comment: Learn about Ajax or iframes.

Comment: Learn how to use jQuery to implement AJAX, specifically the `load` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/), I would recormend [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), to update div.

Something like:

```
     $("#mylink").click (function () {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST", // or GET
           url: "mylink.php",//what ever link you want to load
           data: "someData=someThing&someMore=somethingElse",
           success: function(data){
                  $("#someElement").doSomething().
          }
     });
     return false; 
    });
```